# Plotting OR on Y axis for a mixed effects model in R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble getting the plots I need from a mixed effects regression, and wonder if I could get some help.

I would like to get a dot plot of days on X axis, and OR to have a reaction time slower than 300ms on the Y axis, to see the effect over time.

Using the  sleepstudy data from lme4 as simple sample data. I coerced "day" into a "factor" so that the model would give an OR for each day

```r
df <- data.frame(sleepstudy)

# Generate a categorical value for reaction time to be slower than 300ms
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(slow = ifelse(Reaction >= 300, 1,0), Days = as.factor(Days)) 

# Mixed effects model with subject as random effect
library(lme4)
m <- glmer(slow ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data=df, family=binomial)

library(sjPlot)
plot_model(m)
```

2 issues:

1. The above code gives me a forest plot, which is kind of what I want, except i would like it flipped on the side with the OR on the Y axis and days running along the X axis.
2. My real data has 8 predictors, and I would like to only plot the effect for the predictor "Days" - however once I convert it to a factor, the argument "terms" needs me to spell out every day individual , i.e.

   plot_model(m, terms = c("Days1", "Days2", "Days3" etc))

The alternative is to rm.terms, but that means I need to type out 7 terms to remove. Is there a more efficient way for it to just plot all levels along "Days"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this helps as a starting point?

```r
library(tidyverse)
m %>%
    fixef() %>%
    enframe() %>%
    filter(!str_detect(name, "Intercept")) %>%
    mutate(value = exp(value)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(name, value)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Some further comments:

1. If you have more days, you probably need to make sure that the factor levels have the correct order; i.e. you need to avoid that Day10 comes before Day2 (which will happen with the default lexicographic ordering).
2. These are only the fixed effect point estimates. You could also modify the code to include confidence intervals.

---

To include confidence bands for the estimates you can use the fantastic `broom.mixed` extension to get a tidy table of estimates.

```r
library(broom.mixed)
m %>%
    tidy(effects = "fixed", conf.int = TRUE) %>%
    filter(!str_detect(term, "Intercept")) %>%
    mutate(across(c(estimate, starts_with("conf")), exp)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(term, estimate)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) + 
    scale_y_log10(labels = function(x) sprintf("%g", x))
```

[image]

Comment: this was great! I suspected I had to manual plot the estimates independently - this really makes it simple

Comment: Also just for this comment: If you have more days, you probably need to make sure that the factor levels have the correct order - whats the best way to avoid this?  can you redefine how the factors are named

Comment: Yes you probably will need to explicitly define the order of the factor levels. This will depend on the name of the categorical variable and how many levels there are. For example, assuming there are 12 `Days` levels, you will have Days1, ... , Days11 but without fixing the ordering this will become Days1, Days10, Days11, Days2, ... when plotting. So you'd need to do something along the lines of `m %>% tidy(effects = "fixed", conf.int = TRUE) %>% mutate(Days = factor(Days, levels = paste0("Days", 1:11))) %>% ...` to "fix" the ordering for the plotting.

Comment: On a side note: Why have `Days` as a categorical variable in the first place? Why not as a numeric (continuous) variable?

Comment: when I had it as a numerical variable the plot_model function didn't report individual odd ratio for each "level" - i'll try it again with a numerical structure since i'm now using GGplot